# Acceder a historial completo con WebView

Tags: android, webview

Mi aplicación integra un navegador web y utiliza un botón para mostrar el historial en un ListView, código del botón:

```
private void showHistory(){
    WebBackForwardList currentList = myWebView.copyBackForwardList();
    int currentSize = currentList.getSize();
    String[] history = new String[currentSize];
    for(int i = 0; i < currentSize; ++i){
        WebHistoryItem item = currentList.getItemAtIndex(i);
        history[i] = item.getTitle();
    }
    ArrayAdapter <String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, history);
    lv_history.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Funciona pero solamente muestra el historial de la sesión actual, cuando cierro la aplicación y la vuelvo a abrir parece que se borra el historial de sesiones pasadas

Comment: El web view no guarda esa informacion de forma persistente, sino que la mantiene en memoria, por lo  que al cerrar la aplicacion se destruye el webView y los datos se pierden, necesitas guardar esa informacion en un archivo o base de datos para poder recuperarla cuando tu app vuelva a abrir

Comment: No sabía eso, muchas gracias